# C# - Visual Studio 2017 - Get actual code of predefined methods

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I'm curious but I just couldn't find anything on a quick search.

How can I display how e.g `String.Concat(String0, String1);`
 is processed within the debugging? I'd be interessted in both the actual processor code (like assembler) and and the actually processed c# code (as if it was a self written method).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official guide is at [How to: Debug .NET Framework Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc667410.aspx).

Quick way:

Options -> Debugging -> Enable .NET Framework source stepping.

Since you most likely don't have the sources set up you should see:
[image]

and click view disassembly.

String.cs can be seen here:

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs

Comment: Thanks a lot. Exactly what I was looking for